# How the clipboard works

Tags: 18.04, cinnamon, clipboard

Sometimes I have different contents in the clipboard if I do ctrl+v and paste with right-click and past, I get different output. For example if I copy a secret from my bitwarden app then that comes out from ctrl+v but if I copy a git clone url from github then that only comes out from right+click...paste.

I have install Diodon cliboard manager now to see if it helps me.

Comment: Can you confirm you are using 18.04? In more recent versions of Ubuntu, there are issues with the clipboard on Xorg, which have still not bee fully solved in 20.04. As far as i know, 18.04 should not have that issue, because it was introduced with a newer version of the window manager mutter.

Comment: @vanadium Yes I thought that 18.04 was the latest LTS. That is the one I have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the contents of the clipboard stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/729360/where-are-the-contents-of-the-clipboard-stored)

Answer (score 3):

Please check this article: [The two clipboards in Linux](https://codeyarns.com/2017/01/18/the-two-clipboards-in-linux/)

## X clipboard

The **X window** system has its own clipboard. It is also known as a **cutbuffer**. Any text or content you mark by highlighting with the mouse cursor is automatically copied to this clipboard. This is known as the **PRIMARY selection** or **X Window selection** or just **selection** in X jargon. When you middle-click the mouse cursor at the destination location, this copied content is pasted there.

## Window manager clipboard

In addition to the **X clipboard**, your window manager or desktop environment (like KDE or GNOME) typically maintains its own clipboard. It might even have a clipboard manager which can maintain a historical buffer of content copied to the clipboard.

Typically, text or content is copied to this clipboard when you highlight it and use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+C` or **right-click** with the mouse and choose **Copy**. Content from this clipboard is pasted when you use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+V` or **right-click** with the mouse and choose **Paste**.