# How to find the current clipboard manager via terminal?

Tags: clipboard

Is there a command in terminal and tells the user what is the defualt clipboard manager?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no command in the terminal that tells the user what the default clipboard manager is. That is because such thing as a "default clipboard manager" does not exist. Different clipboards are implemented in a Linux system, and each is used in one specific way [as indicated in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/729372/558158).

There are command line tools that allow to interact with each of these clipboards from the command line, e.g. `xclip` and `xsel` (not installed by default in Ubuntu). When putting contents on a clipboard or reading contents from a clipboard, the clipboard to work with can be specified on the command line. Both by default, i.e., if you do not specify a clipboard yourself, use the PRIMARY clipboard. These tools only work on Xorg. For Wayland, a tool `wl-clipboard` is available.